# How to align the linux output using python

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

I am trying to get the output of a `bash` command to be aligned.

This is the command I am using now. I execute this `bash` command using `python` and it works fine, so I am not going to post that part.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | awk '/Completed/ {print $1}'
```

and I get this output to a variable called `output`

and this is it's output

```
akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
keycloak-setupbhnhc-zskhw               Completed
vault-renew-tokens-1576378800-6dp98             Completed
```

This is how it looks when I normally print it using `print(output)`

But I am using this `output` variable like this.

```
print("here is the output: "+constant.ICON+output+")
```

and my output now looks like this:

```
 - here is the output:                                                                                                                                                                                    
             ● - akamai-1576227900-wrkct               Completed
akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576400700-6m84q         Completed
akamai-1576487100-bnrg7         Completed
akamai-1576573500-g48lq         Completed
akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
keycloak-setupbhnhc-zskhw               Completed
vault-renew-tokens-1576378800-6dp98             Completed
```

It is not aligned properly.

What I really want it is like this:

```
 - here is the output:                                                                                                                                                                                   
             ● - akamai-1576227900-wrkct         Completed
                 akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
                 akamai-1576400700-6m84q         Completed
                 akamai-1576487100-bnrg7         Completed
                 akamai-1576573500-g48lq         Completed
                 akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
                 akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
```

How can I do this?

I was thinking to take the `bash` command output to an array so I can do this properly, but I couldn't get output to an `array`

any good way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use python, just pipe it to `column -t`:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | awk '/Completed/ {print $1}' | column -t
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file.txt
akamai-1576314300-xhf78         Completed                                                                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576659900-npb6g         Completed
akamai-1576746300-6vdjm         Completed
keycloak-setupbhnhc-zskhw               Completed
vault-renew-tokens-1576378800-6dp98             Completed
```

-

```
$ cat file.txt | column -t
akamai-1576314300-xhf78              Completed
akamai-1576659900-npb6g              Completed
akamai-1576746300-6vdjm              Completed
keycloak-setupbhnhc-zskhw            Completed
vault-renew-tokens-1576378800-6dp98  Completed
```

Comment: honestly this answers my other problem, not the one I asked. what I want is there are white spaces before every row. I don't know how to add them. `column -t` only make it more like justify. what I want is to add a constant number of spaces infront  of each row